# Are there other frameworks in macOS that have useful env vars like CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS

Tags: macos, debugging, logging

If you write some code that sends CoreGraphics a bad value, it will tell you about the `CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS` environment variable:

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: set CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable to see the details

This is very helpful! It will even give you a stack trace of where things went wrong if you set `CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE`:

> Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.
>   2019-09-19 20:18:17.373382-0700 CGErrorsTest[22319:1448474] [com.example.CGErrorsTest] If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Are there other frameworks in macOS or iOS that have similar environment variables that give additional logging information?

Comment: You could go through each Binary in the Frameworks (/System/Library/Frameworks) , get the strings and grep them: `strings /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/Current/CoreGraphics | grep -i "environmental variable"`

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll give it a try and see what I find.

Comment: OK, I did that and found a few. IF you want the bounty, post your comment as an answer and I'll award it to you.

Comment: If you're not already aware of it, see <https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2124/_index.html>.

Comment: Oh, cool! I had seen that before but completely forgot about it!

Answer (score 0):

Per @defense2000x's suggestion, I wrote a shell script to run strings on all the frameworks in /System/Library/Frameworks/ and `grep`ed for "env". This turned up only one 2 other frameworks with obvious environment variables: CoreAnimation and OpenCL. CA has this string in it:

> Uncommitted CATransaction. Set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to debug.

OpenCL has this one:

> Unknown CL_LOG_ERRORS environment variable setting: "%s".  Expected: { console, stderr, stdout }
>
> Error:  unknown CL_LOG_ERRORS environment variable setting: "%s"
>
> Error: Ignoring unknown CL_LOG_ERRORS environment variable setting: "%s"

It's not clear what values that one can take on, but since OpenCL is deprecated on macOS, I guess it doesn't matter much.

This is the script I used to find the above:

```
#!/bin/sh

LIBS=`ls -1 /System/Library/Frameworks/`

for LIB in $LIBS; do
    LIB_NO_FRAMEWORK=`echo $LIB | awk -F\. '{ print $1; }'`;
    FULL_LIB=$LIB/Versions/Current/$LIB_NO_FRAMEWORK
    echo working on: $FULL_LIB;
    strings $FULL_LIB | grep -i "env"; 
done
```